# Connect to other Azure account in VS Code's Docker extension

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code with extensions for Azure and Docker. In the Docker extension I logged in with an Azure account to have access to its container registry, which I want to change to a different Azure account.

[image]

In the docker extension, I was prompted to login with Azure to have access to the registries of the account.
Now, I want to switch to a different Azure-account. In the Azure-extension I'm not signed in to any account and in the Docker extension I disconnected my previous Azure registry connection. However, when I want to connect to Azure again it does not prompt me to login again, but instead reconnects to the previous Azure connection.
I can't find where to disconnect and prompt a relogin. How can I do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i had this issue and spent a good 4 hours looking how to sign out and i swear one you find it you are going to scream.

- first right click on the Docker extension and make sure Accounts is
  checked.
- Second on the bottom left corner on top of the setting icon a user icon will pop up click on it and it will give you the option to sign out.
- Go back to the Azure extension and right click it and disconnect and open it up again and will tell you to sign into a azure account.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy to fix.
Since Vs code store's session that's why it automatically logged in.

The easiest way to solve this issue is by logging out in azure.

here are the steps to log out...

1. Open Command Pallete (Press Ctrl+Shift+P)
2. Select Azure Sign Out Option
   [image: Azure Sign Out]
3. Sign in Again in Azure Extension

[image: Azure Sign In]

Mark this answer as Solution if it solve your issue

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't it. I am signed out in the Azure extension and it seems the Azure session in the Docker extension is independent of the login session in the Azure extension.